# Wrong form submission using Enter Key when there are two submit buttons

Tags: html

I have a form with two submit buttons - one for Cancel and the other is for Saving form values to the DB . When Enter key is pressed, the Cancel button submits the form instead of the Save button submitting the form. How can I make the Save button submit the form when Enter key is pressed?

Thanks,

Comment: You can use reset button for Cancel

Comment: When the Cancel button is pressed, the user should be navigated to a different page. Can I do that using reset button? Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your form should not have two submit buttons. Have the Save button be of type submit, and the Cancel button be of type button.

EDIT: I'm going to update this answer to handle several issues that were brought up.

Nothing I've seen in the HTML specification (i.e. the [DTD](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/sgml/dtd.html)) disallows two submit buttons in one form, but the exact issue the OP mentioned can occur. In his or her case, the solution is to make the Cancel button of type button and add in the following JavaScript:

```
<input type="button" value="Cancel" onclick="window.location.href='nextpage.html';"/>
```

Here, one would replace `nextpage.html` with the appropriate URL. Or, `this.form.action` can be the new location if the redirection is to the action of the form.

If the OP wants to be safe and avoid JavaScript, this could only be a (perhaps styled) hyperlink.

Comment: It's perfectly okay to have multiple submit buttons in a form. The real problem is the erratic behavor of browsers when this is the case. Besides, the Cancel button won't submit the form if it's not an `<input>` button.

Comment: Yes, it's allowed according to the DTD, but as you've said, browsers are not equipped to handle this case well. The solution would be to keep one submit button and use JavaScript on the other (if absolutely necessary). Perhaps the OP can clarify the purpose of the Cancel button.

Comment: the HTML spec does not define the default activation order for multiple submit button when the keyboard focus is not in one of them; it specifies the activation behavior only when the focus is on the submit element itself. don't blame the browsers for not implementing something that's not specified. :-)

Comment: Indeed. And anyway I can't think of a logical way to define that behavior!