# Form with more submits and submiting by Enter

Tags: html, forms, post, submit, form-submit

This question is somehow similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3200838/wrong-form-submission-using-enter-key-when-there-are-two-submit-buttons).

I have a form in my ecommerce solution. When you insert something into the cart, you can change number of items. The cart is whole in one form. The form has two submit buttons - recalcualte and continue (which will take buyer to Step 2 of the process).

---

When user changes the number of items using the inputs, he can either hit recalculate (which sends post to app that will change the numbers in session/db) or continue (that will also send the post data to recalculate and then take user to the step 2).

But when user hits enter, the recalculate button takes precedence.

What I want is to make the recalculate button submit the form, but ONLY when clicked and NOT when submited by pressing enter. In contrast the "continue" button should work also with enter.

The solution MUST NOT use javascript as the frontend has to be useable without JS enabled.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the button that takes precedence first in your html sourcecode, and use markup to invert the position of the two buttons?

#### Edit: you say your layout can't handle that.

Either:
 1. Change the layout. Functionality is more important, and for layout there is more than one way to do it.
 2. Have the form not check if "recalculate" or "submit" was pressed, but rather if the shown price was correct with the calculated prize. Example:

User buys 1 item, value 3 dollar.
User buys 2 items, value 5 dollar.
Total prize: 13 dollar.

User now changes the 1 item into 4 items. 3 dollar becomes 12 dollar, but he doesn't hit recalculate.

Have a field in your form that shows the total amount (a hidden field is nicest). When the user submits the form, redo the calculation. If the calculated prize equals the prize in the hidden field, the user knew the final correct prize. If it differs, reshow the form mentioning "You changed your shopping cart, the total prize has been updated to reflect these changes. Verify the amount and submit to purchase" or something.

Comment: I'm not sure if that can be done (i.e. might be a CSS problem as there is a lot of HTML in between the buttons). It's a pity, that the type="button" won't submit the form :( That would be lovely you can have as many buttons to submit as you want but only the type="submit" would be used when submiting with enter/javascript

Comment: So, you  cannot manipulate the HTML, and you can't use Javascript, and you want to solve this problem which already each browser treats differently?

Comment: I can modify HTML, but I can't switch the position of the buttons :( It's undoable using CSS for the layout I have :(

Comment: Edited the answer with another possible solution, then.

Comment: That is VERY GOOD option! Thank you. I'll try it and accept this answer afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="text" id="mytext" ... />
<script type="text/javascript">
document.getElementById("mytext").onkeyup = function(event) {
  if(event.keyCode=='13' || event.keyCode=='10') {
    alert('you pressed enter');
    // do whatever you want when enter is detected
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Did you read the `The solution MUST NOT use javascript as the frontend has to be useable without JS enabled.` part?

Comment: ok sorry, then rearrange the buttons in the markup. the first will get the focus (in most browsers). Then use CSS to change the order of the buttons on the display layer again.

Comment: Yes it would be, problem is that there is a lot of HTML in between them :( I'll ask my CSS coder - he's a wizard! :D

Answer (score -1):

You should be able to decide that server-side. When a button is clicked it's name-value pair is submitted, but when `return` is pressed it isn't. So change your server-side script to do "recalculate" when the recalculate name-value is submitted and to contine in all other cases.

Comment: Actually, I just tested that: when you hit enter, the browser appears to submit the form using the first button it found, and it does pass that button name (tested using Opera).

Comment: This is what i got when I submit it using enter:   ["recalculate"]=>
  string(13) "Recalculate"